# Angular validation message for required input after touched

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Angular reactive forms and I found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/public/docs/_examples/cb-form-validation/ts/src/app/reactive/hero-form-reactive.component.ts) validation idea. It's pretty great but there is one problem. When the form is empty and I click on input, then it is going to get invalid class (red color) but no error message is display. Only after I put some text and delete it, the message will arrive. I am wondering how can I change this 'if steatment' to work as it shoud

```
if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid)
```

I just want to add error message which will occur after I click on input and then leave it (still) empty. Do You have any idea how to achive it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set name control to following:

```
...name: ["", [Validators.required],....
```

then should be able to do the following:

```
<span class="error" *ngIf="(user.get('username').touched && !user.get('username').value) ||  user.get('username').invalid">Error on username</span>
```

or, if you mind about the layout change (as *ngIf will remove it from the DOM), you can apply [hidden] property with the reverse logic:

```
<span class="error" [hidden]="!user.get('username').touched || user.get('username').value || user.get('username').invalid">
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VEvXElJ7HIgZXltF977P)

Comment: Good try but validationMessages are empty so no info will be display. But maybe I can solve it by adding another label.

Comment: then the second one         <label *ngIf="user.get('username').touched && !user.get('username').value">error</label> should work

Comment: Yes. It is a solution, not perfect but it works. It seems like one label handles text change and another a click change. TY for your help.

Comment: Of course it could be any selector but I meant that there need to be 2 ;) Do You have any other idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Its tough to answer without a working example, but in general, I use the opposite logic to what you're doing. Basically, specify the conditions when you wouldn't show the error, and always show it otherwise. For me that's usually

```
 (!password.touched || (password.touched && password.valid))
```

For example. Also, don't forget about 'pristine'.